# Check when a table is indexed (both nil and non-nil key)

Tags: lua

Is it possible to check when a table is indexed, even if the key exists?

I looked into the `__index` metamethod but it is only fired when a table is indexed with a `nil` value.

Comment: [Proxy tables](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; As @Egor referenced, ["The only way to catch all accesses to a table is to keep it empty."](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html) The solution is to not give access to the table where values are stored.

This works well with a factory method (`track`, ibid) to create the table, proxy table and proxy table metamethods.

You could also fold it into the "new" method in any of the various class/prototype systems that people developed in Lua.